# Recommended number of partitions in Cassandra

Tags: cassandra, partitioning, database-partitioning

Although Cassandra allows -2^63 to +2^63-1 number of paritions, is there a recommended max number of partitions beyond which performance might suffer?

Comment: Partitions are based on consistent hashing, so ideally there should not be any kind of performance hit.

Answer (score 3):

After about 1 billion partitions per node full repairs (non incremental) begin to have pretty serious issues with over streaming. Particularly with smaller partitions as the validation compactions run slower.

Ideally i would recommend it by partition *size* not count. Somewhere around 100mb partitions and you will have more efficient compactions without too much of the expensive overhead of the partition index on reads. I wouldn't be too strict on it though as its very hand wavey on a lot of factors. Try to focus on modeling for your queries first then fine tune it if the said model ends up having too large or too many too small partitions (hundreds of millions or more sub 1k or any multi gb ~ish -- per node not total)

Comment: Hi Chris, could you provide more information about issues you had with table with more than 1 billion partitions ? (Cassandra JIRA or other)

Comment: It's 1 billion _per node_ in a table. Have had way more than 1 billion fine but needed to scale out cluster so repairs didnt become problem.

Merkle tree depth is limited so after a certain point the repairs will end up representing and likely over streaming more. Also smaller partitions are less efficient to compact so if your compactions are slower + overstreaming on repairs you will eventually get behind on compaction and things will blow up.

Comment: Thanks Chris for your answer, just to be more precise, are you talking about full repair ? I'm using Apache Reaper to execute repairs on my cluster which execute repair on cluster's segment of tokens. So I think the 1 billions per node per table limit doesn't apply to my case. Notice that my question is just for the understanding, I'm far away from this value.

Comment: I am referring to with using splits like in reaper. There gets to be a point (ie a billion) where the splits needed to maintain a ~2^24 sized merkle tree becomes too much. Ie if using 256 splits in reaper with 1 billion your ok, but after that it quickly becomes so many that the overhead of the individual repairs becomes a problem as well to maintain the leaf=partition key in the merkle tree.

Incremental repair actually does fix most of this though - if you can run it (big if)

Comment: Thanks again for your answer. I have planned to upgrade to Cassandra 4 in September (I'm using the 3.0.28 version). It seems the incremental repair works well on its version. Do agree with that ?

Comment: yes if you are starting with incremental repair. Enabling IR on a cluster that doesnt have it enabled is hard though.

Comment: Chris, I don't understand the link between a 2^24 sized merkle tree and the number of 1 billion partitions.